# Why do some fontawesome icons not render in the html?

Tags: html, frontend, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to add some [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/start) icons to a html document that is rendered to `html` from `rst`. Some icons are rendered and some are not.

This is the `index.rst` file:

```
Test page
================================

Here is a test Table

.. csv-table::
   :stub-columns: 1
   :header: , Column1 |globe|, Column2 |grapes|, Column3 |bolt|, Column4 |wrench2|, Column5 |graph|

   Row1 |wrench|,, some element, element 2, element 3, test
   Row2 |flask|,, , element row 2, element row 2, test
   


.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   The Ecosystem <self>


.. |wrench2| raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>

.. |wrench| raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>

.. |graph| raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-diagram-project"></i>

.. |grapes| raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-grapes"></i>

.. |flask| raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>

.. |bolt| raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>

.. |globe| raw:: html

   <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
```

and the `conf.py` file is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/A3b5EzBi) and the `custom.css` file is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/jW4xnXwA). The command I use to create the documentation is:

```
sphinx-build -M html source build -v
```

where you have the source files in `source`.
You have to install some extra theme:

```
pip install sphinx-bluebrain-theme
```

In the end I get a render like this

[image]

where there are icons for Column 1, 3 and 4, but missing for the other columns. But as far as I have seen all is the same.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: fa-grapes for example is a pro icon and requires the licensed version of fontawesome

Comment: Ah interesting. I did not know there exist pro icons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the icons it looks like you are using version 4.0 https://fontawesome.com/v4/icons/

The missing icons were added in later editions.

Comment: That might be the case. Any way to find out?

Comment: You can find the version info at the top of the css file for example